# Electron iframe: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, iframe, electron, require

I want to embed a HTML file inside of my electron app. I chose to use iframe, however - when I do this - it seems like I can no longer use node.js. Any attempt at using require("electron") will show that require is not defined. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

- Stijn

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind a late answer, you should probably use a `<webview>`, as it gives you a more fine grained control on what you need.
If, however, you really need to use an `<iframe>`, you have two choices:

1. use parent.require (parent accesses the iframe parent, which should be your window)
2. on the load event, copy the parent window's require to the iframe one:

```
iframe.onload = function () {
  const iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow
  iframeWin.require = window.require
})
```

The only "downside" is that your included packages will be accessing the main window DOM instead of the iframe's one, which means that none of the iframe window global variables will exist and, more importantly, document will access the window DOM (querySelector and getElemementBy methods won't really work). Whether this is a problem for you depends on how you organise your code, so good luck there

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this question was old, and didn't have a solved answer.

I had tried using the answer provided since I was experiencing the same problem, but that didn't seem to work.

This probably occurred because it is waiting for all the scripts to load before setting the require function. This caused require to still be undefined on the script load.

To fix this, I set the require function from the iframe, rather than the parent.

```
window.require = parent.window.require;
```